# What is this kind of git process? 502 error on gitlab

Tags: git, gitlab

[WTH is this process?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KNAcT.png)

this gitlab is on server about 2years ago, but recently, this local gitlab shows me 502 error at starting page.

i restart gitlab by 'gitlab-ctl restart', but it doensn't solved

i checked 'gitlab-ctl status', and it seems gitlab-exporter is going down and restart and down again and again. and so unicorn process too.

only way to solve my gitlab is 'gitlab-ctl reconfigure' and 'systemctl stop gitlab-svrundir' and start again...

but about 1 ~ 2 hours later, gitlab is going down again and show 502 error.

then i found this strange process. i don't see this process before recently and it looks sooo weird. it seems this process kills my system but i don't know what this process is.

is there anyone experienced this problem like me? i'm not sure what to do.

i have enough spaces and memory left

Comment: Don't know for sure, but something using all CPUs flat out, with a weird name, seems like it's probably a cryptominer or other malware stealing your resources.

Comment: thx for your reply. i'll check things

Answer (score 0):

Looking at this - weird, 'random' name, killing all the CPU - this probably is a cryptominer. Check if you've had (or still have) a [vulnerable GitLab version](https://about.gitlab.com/releases/2021/04/14/security-release-gitlab-13-10-3-released/) installed. I suggest taking a backup, restoring and updating your instance on a fresh operating system.

Comment: thx for your reply. i'll check things